# ASP.NET MVC C# Select and Where Statements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having trouble understanding .Select and .Where statements. What I want to do is select a specific column with "where" criteria based on another column.

For example, what I have is this:

```
var engineers = db.engineers;
var managers = db.ManagersToEngineers;
List<ManagerToEngineer> matchedManager = null;
Engineer matchedEngineer = null;

if (this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    var userEmail = this.User.Identity.Name;
    matchedEngineer = engineers.Where(x => x.email == userEmail).FirstOrDefault();
    matchedManager = managers.Select(x => x.ManagerId).Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId).ToList();
}
if (matchedEngineer != null)
{
    ViewBag.EngineerId = new SelectList(new List<Engineer> { matchedEngineer }, "PersonId", "FullName");
    ViewBag.ManagerId = new SelectList(matchedManager, "PersonId", "FullName");
}
```

What I'm trying to do above is select from a table that matches Managers to Engineers and select a list of managers based on the engineer's id. This isn't working and when I go like:

```
matchedManager = managers.Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId).ToList();
```

I don't get any errors but I'm not selecting the right column. In fact the moment I'm not sure what I'm selecting. Plus I get the error:

> Non-static method requires a target.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to to select the manager, then you need to use `FirstOrDefault()` as you used one line above, but if it is expected to have multiple managers returned, then you will need `List<Manager>`, try like:

### Update:

so matchedManager is already `List<T>`, in the case it should be like:

```
matchedManager = managers.Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId).ToList();
```

when you put `Select(x=>x.ManagerId)` after the `Where()` now it will return Collection of `int` not Collection of that type, and as `Where()` is self descriptive, it filters the collection as in sql, and `Select()` projects the collection on the column you specify:

```
List<int> managerIds = managers.Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId)
                         .Select(x=>x.ManagerId).ToList();
```

Comment: Yours seems like the closest answer I think but I don't want a list of int Ids but rather a list of manager names associated with the Id.

Comment: I tried using List<Manager> and .Select(x => x.manager).ToList(); instead which compiled but ended up being empty, despite there being matching data in that table. It makes no sense to me why this is happening.

Comment: Actually nevermind it's not empty, I count 2 items but it's not showing the names. Urgh.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to remember what the methods do is to remember that this is being translated to SQL.

A `.Where()` method will filter the **rows** returned.

A `.Select()` method will filter the **columns** returned.

However, there are a few ways to do that with the way you should have your objects set up.

First, you could get the Engineer, and access its Managers:

```
var engineer = context.Engineers.Find(engineerId);
return engineer.Managers;
```

However, that will first pull the Engineer out of the database, and then go back for all of the Managers. The other way would be to go directly through the Managers.

```
return context.Managers.Where(manager => manager.EngineerId == engineerId).ToList();
```

Although, by the look of the code in your question, you **may** have a cross-reference table (many to many relationship) between Managers and Engineers. In that case, my second example probably wouldn't work. In that case, I would use the first example.

Answer (score 1):

You want to filter data by matching person Id and then selecting manager Id, you need to do following:

```
matchedManager = managers.Where(x => x.EngineerId == matchedEngineer.PersonId).Select(x => x.ManagerId).ToList();
```

In your case, you are selecting the ManagerId first and so you have list of ints, instead of managers from which you can filter data

**Update:**
You also need to check matchedEngineer is not null before retrieving the associated manager. This might be cause of your error

Answer (score 0):

You use "Select" lambda expression to get the field you want, you use "where" to filter results